# AWS CloudSearch query

Tags: amazon-cloudsearch

This is sort of a simple question but I can't find any docs on this, or if its even possible.

I understand you need to sign the request for the document endpoint, but is it possible to do the same for the search endpoint?

I need this because I want to privately allow searches from within an application, but I do not want the outside world to search this data.

I understand I can restrict by IP address, but this is limited because the machines are shared and will not restrict others using that IP address. I also understand I could proxy the request and do checks on the proxy.

The best solution would be to sign the search for me in the same way I can sign the document push.

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 1):

I've run into the exact problem but there's unfortunately no way around this. Cloudsearch only allows search access control using IP addresses [as mentioned in the documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloudsearch/latest/developerguide/configuring-access.html#controlling-domain-endpoint-access).

Comment: Could be a very powerful feature. :(

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution could be to use **API Gateway** as frontend (where you control and api-key for instance) in your application and restrict the CloudSearch access to Lambda only.

The design is then:
**API Gateway <-> Lambda function <-> CloudSearch**